# Spring XD 1.3.1 stream with Cassandra 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-xd, spring-data-cassandra

I am using DSE 5.0.5 which come with Cassandra 3.0.11

I am trying to use Spring XD 1.3.1 to connect to the Cassandra

I have a processor module which processes the data and a sink which actually ingests the data.

I am trying to create stream as below

```
stream create --name ingestion-stream --definition "http --port=9020 

|ingestion-transformer| cassandra-3 --contactPoints='1.2.3.4.' --

keyspace='mykeyspace' --ingestQuery='insert into table1(column1,column2,column3) 

values (?,?,?)'" --deploy
```

The injection-stream is the name, ingestion-transformer is the module which transforms the data. I am almost sure that there is no problem with it.

But in the "cassandra-3" which is a sink module, I am facing problem

The Stream creation fails, giving below error in log

> 2017-02-17T12:45:21+0530 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR
>   DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 boot.SpringApplication - Application
>   startup failed

-- then there are lot of error code----

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]:
>   Circular reference involving containing bean 'cassandraConfiguration'
>   - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'cassandraMapping' threw
>   exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class
>   org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraSimpleTypeHolder

My Sink module is using

cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar and cassandra-driver-dse-3.0.0-alpha5.jar

I have also placed these two in xd/lib/

It was working fine with Cassandra 2.2.5 and Spring XD 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data for Apache Cassandra 1.4.x and earlier do not work with `cassandra-driver-core-3.x` and later. Spring Data for Apache Cassandra 1.4.x supports only driver version 2.1.

Spring Data for Apache Cassandra 1.5.x supports `cassandra-driver-core-3.x` and later.

The driver upgrade from 2.1 to 3.x comes with a series of breaking changes, that's thy you get exceptions on application start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way I can upgrade Cassandra 1.4.x to 1.5.x in spring XD ?

Comment: Also, is there any plan to include spring-data-cassandra 1.5.x integration in Spring-XD releases ?